# What is the purpose of capitalization? how are capitalized words read?

Tags: capitalization

I know that proper nouns are capitalized but why is it even necessary? are all capitalized words read in the same way as non capitalized ones?

Comment: Yes - the distinction is only made _in writing_.

Comment: If for some reason you needed to distinguish China (the country) from china (the material) you would say China with a capital C but otherwise as @KateBunting suggests we read them aloud exactly the same.

Comment: @mdewey what is china the material?

Comment: The material cups and saucers are made of.

Comment: A [***capitonym***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitonym#:~:text=A%20capitonym%20is%20a%20word,a%20proper%20noun%20or%20eponym.&text=A%20capitonym%20is%20a%20form,also%20a%20form%20of%20heteronym.) is a word that changes its meaning (and sometimes pronunciation) when it is capitalized. For an example where the pronunciation changes, capitalised ***August*** (the month) has stress on the *first* syllable, whereas adjectival ***august*** (majestic, imperial) has stress on the *second* syllable. Another such pair are ***Polish*** (from Poland) and ***polish*** (rub, shine).

Comment: the word "August" how do we know that it is a month and not the name of someone? since both proper nouns and months are capitalized

Comment: From the context. (_August_ isn't used as a man's name in English, though _Augustus_ used to be.)

Comment: Why isn't August used as a man's English? can't any word be a name?

Comment: @KateBunting [**August** is most certainly used as a man's name in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/August_Wilson) although I agree it's not *common*.

Comment: https://fia.umd.edu/answer-why-all-the-crazy-capital-letters/

Comment: @stangdon I stand corrected (though I see August Wilson was of German descent).

Comment: @mdewey I think _saying China with a capital C_ may read differently from _saying 'China with a capital C'_.

Comment: @KateBunting did I see stangdon in August?

Comment: so the only way to know whether or not August is a person's name or the month is through context? if that is the case then it makes no sense to capitalize the months since it still can have many meanings?

Comment: To revert to "Why is it necessary?" - Because that has become the conventional usage in English. Fewer proper nouns are capitalised in French, all nouns are in German.

Comment: "I am going to Berlin in June, to meet my German friend August." Obviously June means the month and not the girl's name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a feature of English orthography.  English wasn't designed, it evolved.

1500 years ago there were no lower case letters, only capitals.  Scribes developed the lowercase as a quicker forms of writing, but "important" words were still written with capitals.  When English was first written these rules which had applied to Latin were adapted to English, and so the "important" words were written in capitals, with lowercase for other words.  Printing (500 years ago) developed these rules.  It is worth noting that the rules were developed differently in France, Germany and other countries using the Latin letters.

If you decided to design an alphabet, you would not use capital letters. The Cree and Inuktitut syllabary (designed in the 1800s) have none. Similarly Armenian (adapted from Greek before the development of upper and lowercase Greek) has none. English would be no less logical and readable without capital letters. Whereas Japanese has katakana and hiragana (representing the same sound) and Devanagari has the same way of representing the same sound with or without ligatures.

There are some very rare words that change pronunciation with capitalisation, but these are mostly co-incidences:

> Polish / polish  (in the first the "o" is a long dipthong)
>
> Reading / reading  (In the first "ea" is short, like in "red")

So the rules might be dumb. But we don't get to decide the rules.  The fact is that English *does* have capital letters. And it does have rules for using them. And if you don't obey the rules, then your English is judged to be "bad".  So you should just get used to the fact.